Implement a sidebar that remains fixed horizontally when the user scrolls vertically
What I'm Trying to Achieve:
I want to use position: sticky along with top-0 and left-0 (or right-0) to keep a sidebar fixed on the side of the screen, even when scrolling down the page.
The Problem:
Despite applying sticky top-0 left-0 (or right-0 for the right sidebar) in Tailwind CSS to both my left and right sidebars, they do not stay fixed horizontally as intended.
Code:
Here is the code for my Desktop component in pages/Desktop.tsx:
const Desktop: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full relative bg-white overflow-hidden  flex flex-col items-start justify-start">
      <Header />
      <div className="self-stretch h-[936px] flex flex-row items-start justify-between">
        <Leftbar />
        <Center />
        <Rightbar />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

And here is the code for my Leftbar component in src/Components/Leftbar.tsx:
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

const Leftbar: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="self-stretch bg-lavender flex flex-col items-start justify-start h-[95vh] py-0 px-2 text-left text-lg text-gray-100 font-inter border-l-[1px] border-solid sticky top-0 border-lightgray-200 md:hidden">
      {/* Rest of the component code */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Leftbar;

What I've Tried:
I've consulted with ChatGPT for advice and searched through forums like teratail and various internet sources. The consensus seems to be that using position: sticky, top-0, and left-0 (or right-0) should work for my use case. However, I can't figure out why it's not working in my situation.
Details and Results of What I Tried:
Following the suggested solution did not change the behavior of the sidebars; they still won't stay fixed horizontally as I scroll down the page.
Is there a specific detail or a common pitfall I might be missing with Tailwind CSS and the sticky positioning? Any insights, advice, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
Site URL:
https://enterprizegai.netlify.app/
